# Please explain this C++ loop logic

Tags: c++

I created a custom boolean function named "isPrime()", some how I made it work but I don't know why it works, any explanation in plain english will be appreciated.

```
for (i = 3; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (isPrime(i))
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}


// I don't understand why this loop works:

bool isPrime (int i)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)    // 3 / 2
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;  
}
```

As you can see the **isPrime()** function has a loop so once it's finished, it should return **true** anyway because the **return true;** is outside of the loop and compiler will read **return true;** once the loop is finished. How the **isPrime()** function can return **false** when the it is returning true at the end?

Comment: get a debugger, step though the code

Comment: Don't you see that there's also `return false;` inside the loop? That `return false;`, if executed, will immediately exit the function. Why are you ignoring that fact? And if you don't know how `return` works, it is time for a good C++ book.

Comment: @AndreyT I almost forgot that, I thought the loop will repeat and return false many times and then at the end it will return true so the final return value will be true, but I was wrong, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i % j == 0

it will return false and the loop finish

then the last statement "return true" will not run

Answer (score 2):

If a function reaches a `return` statement at any point, it will exit completely, no matter where the return statement is, and control will go to the function who called it (in this case, I am assuming main).

Comment: So the loop breaks after returning the value or it repeat again and again and then check how many true and false values it got then decide?

Comment: `isPrime` will only ever return `true` or `false`. If `isPrime` makes it all the way through its `for` loop without returning false, it will return true. Not only does the loop break, but the function actually exits completely and returns the value. I am referencing the isPrime loop, not the main loop that calls isPrime

Answer (score 0):

Check  this code segment.

```
if (i % j == 0)    // 3 / 2
{
    return false;
}
```

Because of this code segment when the number is divisible by value of j without any remainders function will return FALSE.
Simply when your if condition is true function returns **FALSE**. If method never comes to the inside of if condition then it returns **TRUE**

Answer (score 0):

The function will return only once in execution: and are exit to the called function when return is executed

Logic is that :

a [prime number](http://www.factmonster.com/math/numbers/prime.html) is A prime number can be divided, without a remainder, only by itself and by 1:

so when `i % j == 0` is true means that `j` is a factor of `i` hence it is not a prime so return false and exit the function